# How to find the number of elements having the same CSS selector in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I am using the latest version of selenium with java.

I am trying to find the number of elements in a certain web page having the same css selector, but I don't want to use findElements(By.cssSelector(CSS)).size() because it takes a significant time to "GET" the elements and then find their count. I don't want to get them, I just need to find their count, i.e. how many elements are in this page having the same CSS value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, you need to particular element and get the size

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the elements, then use a size like this, need to locate each tag like //a, //div or //li. Here is one example

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
int count =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a")).size();
System.out.println(count);
```